# Custom subscription preference center interface

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, user-interface

Looking for support or best practice developing custom subscriber preference & subscription centers for SFMC.

I DON'T want a default SmartCapture form. The intention is for a Cloud Pages hosted custom UI, that retrieves and sets subscriber attributes to business unit's specific data extension via **AMPScript / API calls**.

Can anyone provide some documentation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SFMC-hosted custom preferences centers that I've built are landing/microsite pages coded in SFMCs Server-Side JavaScript (SSJS).

You can accomplish nearly all of what you need for subscription/preference center interactions using SSJS.

Here's a simple boilerplate that I use:

https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8

SSJS Reference:

- [Syntax Guide](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/)
- [Core Functions Library](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/)

You can also code your pages in AMPScript, which is faster, but more verbose.  There are also no arrays in AMPScript.

- [AMPScript API functions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/)